# Template Factory Pattern in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, templates, metaprogramming, factory-pattern

I am trying to make a factory that will have the type passed in, rather then having it hard coded for types. However, when I attempt to add the type to the factory inside of the types .cpp file, I will get a linker error. For example, he is a linker error I am currently getting.

1>RandomClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: short __thiscall TemplatedFactory::AddType(char const *)" (??$AddType@VRandomClass@@@TemplatedFactory@@QAEFPBD@Z) referenced in function "void _*cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'private: static short RandomClass::ID''(void)" (??*_E?ID@RandomClass@@0FA@@YAXXZ)

I tried to make the test case as small as possible, though it does cross five files, they are very small

BaseClass.h : http://codepad.org/MhZMw7t0

```
#pragma once
class BaseClass{ };
```

RandomClass.h : http://codepad.org/xoObzP8G

```
#pragma once
#include "BaseClass.h"
class RandomClass : public BaseClass
{
private:
    static short ID;

public:
    RandomClass();
    virtual ~RandomClass();
};
```

TemplatedFactory.h : http://codepad.org/qkcTBw24

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
using std::map;
#include "BaseClass.h"

template<typename Type> BaseClass* createType() { return new Type; }

class TemplatedFactory
{
private:
    typedef BaseClass* (*ComponentFactoryFuncPtr)();
    typedef map<const char*, ComponentFactoryFuncPtr> map_type;

    map_type m_Map;

public:
    static TemplatedFactory &GetInstance();

    template<typename Type>
    short AddType(const char* componentName);
};
```

RandomClass.cpp : http://codepad.org/ALoF3Ysb

```
#include "RandomClass.h"
#include "TemplatedFactory.h"

short RandomClass::ID = TemplatedFactory::GetInstance().AddType<RandomClass>("RandomClass");

RandomClass::RandomClass() { }

RandomClass::~RandomClass() { }
```

TemplatedFactory.cpp : http://codepad.org/iqgNqa6H

```
#include "TemplatedFactory.h"

TemplatedFactory &TemplatedFactory::GetInstance()
{
    static TemplatedFactory instance;
    return instance;
}

template<typename Type>
short TemplatedFactory::AddType(const char* componentName)
{
    ComponentFactoryFuncPtr function = &createType<Type>;
    m_Map.insert(std::make_pair(componentName, function));

    return 0;
}
```

I can remove the the linker error if I move

```
short RandomClass::ID = TemplatedFactory::GetInstance().AddType<RandomClass>("RandomClass");
```

from RandomClass.cpp to TemplatedFactory.cpp, however, I would like to have the declaration in RandomClass.cpp. Does anyone know of a way to fix this or perhaps a better design (without the use of external libraries).

Comment: The real `BaseClass` has at least a virtual destructor, right?

Comment: What happens if you add an implementation to TemplatedFactory.cpp for RandomClass? It make be a problem with trying to link a static class variable to a dynamic implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Templated functions cannot have their definition and declaration separated from each other without `export`, which your compiler probably doesn't support. You need to move the `TemplateFactory::AddType` definition to the header.

Comment: Interesting, if I can't use "export", is there a better design patterns I could use?

Comment: No, there's no better 'pattern' you can use. Template functions are always just implemented in the header. Doing this isn't frowned upon.

Comment: In the Header of TemplateFactory.h or in the Header of RandomClass.h? If I could this in the RandomClass.h header that would be fine too, even if it is with some sort of a static const short

Comment: The `TemplatedFactory::AddType` implementation would need to be moved to TemplatedFactory.h. It doesn't make sense for this to be moved to RandomClass.h, anyway. You can call `TemplatedFactory::AddType` from anywhere, you just can't define it outside of the declaration.

Comment: Oh I see, if I just move the "TemplatedFactory::AddType" function to TemplatedFactory.h, I can then keep "short RandomClass::ID = TemplatedFactory::GetInstance().AddType<RandomClass>("RandomClass");" in my RandomClass.cpp ...

 

Thank you for the help

Comment: Actually, with

short RandomClass::ID = TemplatedFactory::GetInstance().AddType<RandomClass>("RandomClass");
In my RandomClass.cpp, is there any reason that code would not execute if RandomClass was in a library and not explicitly being created?

Comment: If it being a .lib will not allow the code to be executed because it is not explicitly called, will change it to a .dll fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot place implementation of class template in cpp-file
See some technique for "cheating" on http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.14

Comment: Technically, you can do it using external templates. But this is not widely supported by C++ compilers.

Comment: Interesting, if I can't use "export", is there a better design patterns I could use?

Comment: @VladLazarenko If you mean extern template, then it's about explicit instantiation instead of implementation of class template member. There is no way to place template<typename Type> short TemplatedFactory::AddType(const char* componentName) to TemplatedFactory.cpp with extern template – Oleg Svechkarenko 7 mins ago

Comment: you are right, you can't have generic impl in cpp... Well, unless you include it into header :-)))

Comment: Vlad: In the Header of TemplateFactory.h or in the Header of RandomClass.h? If I could this in the RandomClass.h header that would be fine too, even if it is with some sort of a static const short