# Error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘::’ token

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am getting an error when trying to compile my class.

The error:

**Matrix.cpp:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘::’ token**

**Matrix.h**

```
#ifndef _MATRIX_H
#define _MATRIX_H

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix();
    ~Matrix();
    void set_dim(int, int);     // Set dimensions of matrix and initializes array
    unsigned int get_rows();    // Get number of rows
    unsigned int get_cols();    // Get number of columns
    void set_row(T*, int);      // Set a specific row with array of type T
    void set_elem(T*, int, int);// Set a specific index in the matrix with value T
    bool is_square();           // Test to see if matrix is square
    Matrix::Matrix add(Matrix); // Add one matrix to another and return new matrix
    Matrix::Matrix mult(Matrix);// Multiply two matrices and return new matrix
    Matrix::Matrix scalar(int); // Multiply entire matrix by number and return new matrix

private:
    unsigned int _rows;         // Number of rows
    unsigned int _cols;         // Number of columns
    T** _matrix;                // Actual matrix data

};

#endif  /* _MATRIX_H */
```

**Matrix.cpp**

```
#include "Matrix.h"
template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() {
}

Matrix::~Matrix() { // Line 13
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "Matrix.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Matrix<int> m = new Matrix<int>();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `_MATRIX_H` is a reserved identifier (you aren't allowed to use it in your program; it's for the compiler to use).  Any identifier that begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved.  Consider using `MATRIX_H_` instead.

Comment: Also, `Matrix::Matrix add(Matrix);` is wrong. It should be `Matrix add(Matrix);`. More conforming compilers will reject such code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Matrix::~Matrix() { }
```

`Matrix` is a class template.  You got the constructor definition right; the destructor (and any other member function definitions) need to match.

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() { }
```

---

```
Matrix<int> m = new Matrix<int>();
```

This won't work.  `new Matrix<int>()` yields a `Matrix<int>*`, with which you cannot initialize a `Matrix<int>`.  You don't need any initializer here, the following will declare a local variable and call the default constructor:

```
Matrix<int> m;
```

Comment: This worked, but now I recieve the following: main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `Matrix<int>::Matrix()'

Comment: And, as Oleg rightly points out (+1 for that!), you can't separate the class template member functions into a .cpp file:  they have to go in the .h file.  Lots more in the [Parashift C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12)

Comment: Ahh. So I should just implement the entire library in the header file? Thanks, you seem to answer most of my questions.

Answer (score 3):

Define destructor as

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {
}
```

And other error is that you cannot place implementation of class template in .cpp-file [Template Factory Pattern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185502/template-factory-pattern-in-c/5185550#5185550)